Fast way to calculate (AAᵀ)⊙(BBᵀ)
I need a computationally efficient way to calculate $AA^\top \odot BB^\top$, where

$A$ and $B$ are tall, real-valued matrices of the same size ($\text{nrows} \approx \text{ncols}^3$)
$\odot$ stands for the Hadamard product.

My current implementation uses

cblas_?syrk to perform the two regular matrix-matrix transpose products and
a regular loop to do the Hadamard product

Could I do better?

That depends very much on the dimensions of your matrices and your cache hierarchy.

do you need the matrix itself, or do you only need the matrix-vec multiplication for your resulting matrix? If the matrix must be constructed, then it might be hard to optimize the cost. But the mat-vec could have faster ways to compute.

In general, multiplication by a vector DOES NOT distribute over a Hadamard product of matrices
$$\eqalign{
\def\r{\right}
\def\l{\left}
\l(X\odot Y\r)v &\;\ne\; \;Xv \:\odot\, \:Yv \\
v^T\l(X\odot Y\r) &\;\ne\; v^TX \odot\, v^TY \\
}$$
However, it DOES distribute when the vector
is one of the standard basis vectors
$$\eqalign{
\l(X\odot Y\r)e_k &\;=\; Xe_k  \odot\, Ye_k \\
e_k^T\l(X\odot Y\r) &\;=\; e_k^TX \odot\, e_k^TY \\\\
}$$
This suggests a way to calculate the product $\,W = X\odot Y$
one column at a time
$$\eqalign{
We_k &= (Xe_k) \,\odot\, (Ye_k) \\
w_k &= x_k \odot y_k \\
W &= \big[\,w_1\;w_2\,\ldots\, w_n\,\big] \\
}$$
or one row at a time
$$\eqalign{
e_k^TW &= (e_k^TX) \,\odot\, (e_k^TY)
}$$
NB: Matrix-matrix products are not required, only matrix-vector products
$$\eqalign{
\l(AA^T\r)e_k &= A\l(A^Te_k\r) \\
}$$
Even better, the operation $\l(A^Te_k\r)$ simply selects the $k^{th}$ column of $A^T$, so it doesn't actually require a matrix-vector product.
So you really only need two matrix-vector products to calculate each column of $W$ $-$ one for $AA^T$ and one for $BB^T$.
